# ax2009 x++ Error 0x80040211 in RunBaseBatch

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I want to send email in `RunBaseBatch`, but I get error 0x80040211 (unknown).
I found in google that means:

> The message could not be sent to the SMTP server.
>   The transport error code was %2. The server response was %1

```
public void SendReport(str email)
{
   SysMailer      sm = new SysMailer();
   ;
   sm.quickSend("axmail@domain.eu", email, "Test", strfmt("body"));
}
```

This method is called in Run method. And if I copy this source code into job that works. Additionally in Run method I use,

```
permissionSet = new Set(Types::Class);
permissionSet.add(new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop));
permissionSet.add(new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop));
permissionSet.add(new InteropPermission(InteropKind::DllInterop));
CodeAccessPermission::assertMultiple(permissionSet);
```

Comment: Are you saying this same exact code is successful when in non-batch? That indicates it's likely either permission (AOS user vs your user) or tier (executing from server vs client). Do you have IP restrictions by machine? Any other permissions issues?

Comment: yes, in non-batch works properly (without add permission)

Comment: Have you checked your mail server settings? You haven't given enough information to really help solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because your email seems to work in a job (client side), your email settings in AX are not the issue.
This is most likely an authentication issue.

Take a look at this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2015/08/27/isolate-issues-related-to-e-mail-not-sending-from-dynamics-ax-2012-using-the-smtp4dev-tool/), which describes what your are experiencing.

On the client side, your current windows user is used to authenticate with the SMTP server.

In batch, the emails are sent from the AOS. That means that the account used for authentication, is the account under which the AOS service runs.

Your mail server probably doesn't accept connections from everyone.
Take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/533218/control-which-users-can-authenticate-with-windows-smtp-server) on how this is achieved.

You'll have to allow the user that runs your AOS service, to authenticate to your mail server.